# Disable passwordless - User should login with email and password

Tags: auth0

when I log out of Auth0 I can just click on my email to log in again. Making it passwordless.

How do i make the flow so the user has to input email and password to log in instead of having it passwordless?

I couldn't find any docs on this.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Joey - did you see my answer - believe it solves your situation. If you found it helpful / accurate please can you acknowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a live SSO Session - the Auth0 Lock widget will detect this, and therefore offer an abbreviated login whereby password re-entry is not required.

Instead, when you log a user out, ensure you are not just expunging the local session, but also the auth0 sso session. You can do this by simply calling `https://{{YOUR_TENANT}}.auth0.com/v2/logout`

If you are using the `auth0.js` library, then you should find an equivalent function eg. `logout` that achieves the same thing.